# How to overload call operator() function with same type and parameters, but different return type?

Tags: c++

I want to define a new call operator() function with the parameters and type defined for the first operator() function. The reason for doing this is that the operations I want to perform with the new operator() function needs the same parameters as the first one, but maybe named differently but the type I need should remain the same. I know that it is not possible, but could someone suggest any different method to do this or are there any way around?

code listing:

```cpp
namespace correlator {
    class mean_square_displacement
    {
    public: 
        typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::multi_array<float, 2>> sample_type;
        typedef double result_type;  // fixed_vector<double, 3>

    result_type operator() (sample_type const& first, sample_type const& second) const
    { 
        double msd = 0;
        size_t N = first->size(); // number of rows in one frame (11214 in one frame)
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
                double dr = (*first)[i][j] - (*second)[i][j];
                msd += dr * dr;
                //ofile_msd << i << " " << msd << std::endl;
                if (msd > 0)
                    std::cout << "msd::" <<  msd << std::endl;
        } 
    }
    
    return msd/N;
} // first operator ends here 

    double operator()(sample_type const& first, sample_type const& second) const
    {
        std::cout <<  *(*first)[0][0] <<"The first element :." << std::endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
};
} // namespace correlator
```

Comment: You cant *overload* a function/operator solely on the return type. The input parameters must be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapters:

```
struct Foo {
  // these are your current operator() functions
  int op1(int);
  float op2(int);
};

struct FooAdapter1 {
  Foo& foo;
  auto operator()(int i) { return foo.op1(i); }
};

struct FooAdapter2 {
  Foo& foo;
  auto operator()(int i) { return foo.op2(i); }
};
```

So, instead of passing a `Foo` object like this:

```
std::invoke(foo,7); // no
```

You pass it via an adapter:

```
std::invoke(FooAdapter1{foo},7); // calls op1
```

And you give the Adapters good semantically sensible names, of course.

---

Alternatively, use an out argument to select the overload:

```
struct Foo {
  // these are your current operator() functions
  void operator()(int, int&);
  void operator()(int, float&);
};
```

And then the somewhat ugly call:

```
float& result{};
std::invoke(foo,7,result); // selects the fist overload
```

Comment: Thanks! Could it be possible to create new structs/class inside the namespace**{}** and How do compiler distinguish between them?

Comment: @Rohit I don't understand. Can you rephrase? How does the compiler distinguish between *what*? Also see update for a much older method (that is not as clean, IMO).

Comment: For example if first operator() doing some operations using some other function and now if I call the second operator() in main() function how do compiler differentiate between them? The example you gave in your answer create different structs for the two operators, that is why I asked is it possible to create these structs inside the namespace?

Comment: @Rohit `op2` can still call `op1`, that's not an issue. The Adapters merely create a new name with which to call the operators. You can define the adaptors inside your `namespace correlator` -- I don't see what that's got to do with anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload **any** function by changing only the return type.
Instead, you can use **tag dispatching**:

```
struct tag_a{};
struct tag_b{};

struct foo
{
   int operator()(int, tag_a);
   double operator()(int, tag_b);
};

// call example: f(4, tag_a());
```